# Free Visual-studio addin to reformat text

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Hi
I was wondering if there is any free visual studio plugin which allow me to do "clean up code"?. By clean up I mean reformat text, break long lambda expressions in separate lines etc - just like resharper does it. Unfortunatelly I can't use resharper because my laptop is a bit old and it is hard to work with resharper working.

Answer (score 2):

Try [code maid](https://bitbucket.org/s_cadwallader/codemaid/wiki/Home)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will reformat text: CTRL+K, CTRL+D

- [Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2005 IDE Productivity Tips and Tricks](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2006/09/visual-studio-2005-ide-pro_115928263399626169.html) (most apply to 2005 onwards)
- [Visual Studio .NET 2005 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202005%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.htm)

Comment: I know these hotkeys (CTRL+K CTRL+D) but it's not enoguh for me

Comment: @sensorlearner: in that case, I think you need to describe why it's not enough...

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion first thing is that depend on plugin is a futurewise problem for developer because truely developer need thing less then a common developer.

well i try myself Resharper but never found that's good but if you like some good thing that i recommended telerik 's plugin for visual studio 2010. they are good then resharper but both kill the programmer's productivity.